# Java - Sorting ArrayList - Bubble Sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, bubble-sort

I have to sort an arrayList containing the frequency of the purchases of customers. So I can display the output whether in an ascending or descending order. However, I am not quite sure what I am missing but it is not sorting the elements at all. I'd really appreciate any comments or feedback!

This is what I have so far:

```
for(int i=0; i<customers.size(); i++)
{
        for(int k= i+1; k <customers.size(); k++)
        {
                if((customers.get(k)).compareTo(customers.get(i)) < 0)
                {
                        Customer temp = customers.get(i);
                        customers.set(i, customers.get(k));
                        customers.set(k,temp);

                }
        }

        System.out.println(customers.get(i));   
}
```

Comment: I believe that the key is `if((customers.get(k)).compareToIgnoreCase(customers.get(i)) < 0)`. I would recommend to debug and see if it works as you expect.

Comment: Your code is not even valid, compiling Java code. Why don't you use Collections.sort() instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: also, `int = k+1` is `int k = i+1` right?

Comment: `int = k+1` - what? This can't be your real code. Show us, if not your real code, then at least code you've actually tested.

Comment: I am required to use a bubble sort algorithm for this program.

Comment: Totò, Thank you for pointing that out. That was a typo.

Comment: where is your `Customer` class, can you show the `Customer` class code???

Comment: What does your list contain? The text says it contains frequencies (which should thus be numbers), but your code compares with compareToIgnoreCase (which suggests Strings).

Comment: `Customer` class `compareToIgnoreCase(Customer customer)` method code???

Comment: JB Nizet, yes, it does contains the data types String and int

Comment: Ankit Lamba, I have compareToIgnoreCase and CompareTo methods(both returning 0) within the customer class

Comment: So it contains Customer instances. Why don't you share the code?

Comment: @SdlS if both methods **returning 0**, then your `if` condition should-be unreachable; methods `returning 0` OR `returning int` ????

Comment: methods      returning 0 (zero)

Comment: You realize  0 means equal?

Answer (score 0):

keeping *K* = *i*, try this for your inner loop:

```
for(int k= i; k <customers.size() - i -1; k++)
{
```

this should work.

Comment: You don't need to compare the `k`th object to the `i`th object, if `k==i`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the sorted list `System.out.println(customers.get(i));` has to be outside of the sorting loop. Add another loop after that one to print the results

Answer (score 0):

You had a few mistakes,

```
// I tested with List<String>, String temp.
public static void sort(List<Customer> customers) {
  for (int i = 0; i < customers.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int k = i + 1; k < customers.size(); k++) {
      // Compare left to right, not right to left.
      if (customers.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(customers.get(k)) > 0) {
        Customer temp = customers.get(i);
        customers.set(i, customers.get(k));
        customers.set(k, temp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I tested with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] names = { "Bob", "bob", "Alice", "Bob",
      "Carol" };
  List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(
      Arrays.asList(names));
  sort(al);
  for (String str : al) {
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

I got

```
Alice
bob
Bob
Bob
Carol
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int n = yourArray.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if (yourArray.get(j) < yourArray.get(j + 1)) {
                int temp = yourArray.get(j);
                yourArray.set(j, yourArray.get(j + 1));
                yourArray.set(j + 1, temp);`
            }
```